# Verb tense in some special cases?

Tags: tenses

Let's begin with an example pertaining to the combination of verb tense:

- Indeed, Amy's journey ***seems to have rehabilitated*** her from her stressful mind.

Honestly, the phrase ***"seems to have rehabilitated"*** confused me. Nevertheless, I still figured out that in this particular situation, the phrase ***"seems"*** refers to Amy's journey which ***is talked or being talked at present*** while the phrase ***"to have rehabilitated"*** refers to what "Amy's journey" ***did to her in the past***. Is this realization accurate? I will appreciate any help from anyone!

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've ended up with the right conclusion, but your reasoning for getting there is dubious.

*To have rehabilitated her" has no tense of its own: the perfect infinitive expresses a state current at whatever time you are talking about, your 'Reference Time', RT.

The verb of the matrix clause, *seems* is cast in the present form, so we take your RT to be the present. Since the infinitive "borrows" its time reference  from that, it is equivalent to

> **has** [present] rehabilitated her

The sentence may be paraphrased

> It seems that Amy's journey **has** rehabilitated her,

which we infer to be a resultative perfect: the present state which the perfect expresses is that

> She is now rehabilitated.